# How do you complete zombie nimble zombie quick?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I've recently unlocked all the minigames in plants vs zombies 1, but I can't seem to complete zombie nimble zombie quick. The dolphin riders are way too fast! Even if I stop them with tall nuts, then the other zombies on the pool lanes gobble up the tall nut. Or even if I manage to stop the pool lane zombies from advancing, the land lane zombies finish me off. Is there a way past this minigame?

Note: if this helps I missed some sun since they were coming out too fast and I was too busy defending from the zombies so mabey thats the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dolphin Zombies can be forced of their dolphins by something as simple as a lily pad, once they reach a plant even if it's only a lily they will jump over it and discard their dolphins.

For early sun gain use potato mines to blow them up so you can save the sun and build one or maybe even two extra sunflowers before planting your first permanent attacker. And if you time it well with mines you might be able to save up enough sun to build only cattails that are able to cover all lanes with ease as long as you keep them alive with pumpkins.